# Mongoose not working with mLab when hosted on Herkou but works when hosted locally

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mlab

I have a working app when i run it locally but when i deployed it to heroku using mlab it is unable to create the collection it had created locally here is the code to connected to the db locally just with heroku process.env.MONGODB_URI which logs the correct URI

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
mongoose.connect("process.env.MONGODB_URI", { useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
```

Comment: Have you set you environment variables in Heroku? Also, remove quotes around `process.env.MONGODB_URI`

Comment: it was the quotes thank you for helping